# How to make a while loop by dialogflow intents?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have the following intent and followup intents for a user login process:

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic0]

[image: Pic2]

[image: Pic3]

[image: Pic4]

How can I set a while loop for this login process in order to continue asking user email while user enters email address incorrectly and after he/she enters it correctly the getting password intent triggers?
In my cases after 2 incorrect entry, api.ai will response "Not Available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing users to respond to a question without giving them recourse to cancel, move to another part of your conversational interface or speak about another subject is user-hostile and I'd recommend doing exactly what Actions on Google forces you to do in this situation: end the conversation after a few failed attempts.

Conversational interfaces are best thought of as designing actual conversations.  In a normal conversation asking the same question multiple times regardless of what someones says to you would largely be considered annoying at best.  Consider revising your Dialogflow agent to allow logged-out conversations explaining to the user what your agent can offer and why login is required for certain features.  If the user repeatedly asks for a feature that requires login but refuses to do so, the conversation should end.

Another note here: I'd recommend against using passwords through conversational interfaces.  Most conversational platforms have a way to sign in (e.g. [Google Assistant/Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#during_the_conversation)) or you can safely assume the user is using a device where they have access to a web browser as well (Slack) and you can use a system like [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to properly authenticate users.

Comment: It is a good idea to loop some question of section of questions (intents) but with option to cancel. For example when you need to validate something you shouldn't stop after 3 tries enter the validation code (for example from sms). But I agree with option to cancel dialog or the section is in loop.